# Sudden slowdown in performance despite very little CPU usage

Tags: performance

I recently had some basic applications (web browser, pdf viewer, idle terminal) open on my Ubuntu system, all of which initially ran well with fast performance. After a few minutes away from my computer, I came back to find them all running extremely slowly.

I closed all of these applications and opened gnome-system-monitor by itself. This application showed nothing using more than 2% of cpu and no significant memory usage relative to the specs of my system. At this point, all performance was very slow, and most button presses took a significant period of time (maybe 10 seconds) to register on screen. The fans on my PC seemed to be running at a high intensity the entire time.

The problem went away after I restarted. If it happens again, what else can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Would keep an eye on temperature, slow computer plus high fans use sounds like high temp problem.  It could also be other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `System Monitor` app, pull down the hamburger menu, and assure that **All Processes** is enabled. Then you'll see what process was chewing up your CPU, and why your fans were running full time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep this in mind for the next time it happens. I'll accept this answer for now, although I may update if the mystery continues at some point.

Comment: @KevinBradner Since your question was *"If it happens again, what else can I do to diagnose the problem?"*, and my answer addressed that problem, your accept is ok. If the problem reoccurs, please start a new question with the best details that you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to checking your system monitor, you can also check your logs to see if there are errors that didn't necessarily cause high CPU usage but still slow things down. One familiar one is irqpoll issues which don't necessarily increase CPU usage but may make things run slower.

I find the easiest way to do this is with a GUI application. You can always read your logs from the terminal, but I prefer a graphical user interface for this. The one that I prefer is called `KSystemLog` and it's in your default repositories. With KSystemLog you can see your System, Kernel, Authentication, X.Org, and Journald logs in one central application.

To install, just open your terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install ksystemlog
```

Follow the prompts, by entering your password, and it'll install itself. Once installed, it will appear in your 'System Tools' folder. Once opened, it will look a bit like this:

[image]

(Unfortunately, I don't have any images saved with a bunch of errors.)

Open it and look for errors. If you find any errors, you can copy the entire error message line, paste it into your favorite search engine, and *potentially* find solutions. If you can't find the solutions by searching, you can ask at appropriate forums and have specific information to pass on to those trying to help you.

**Note:** The log viewer is meant for those using KDE, but doesn't pull in a bunch of other files and is remarkably light. You can read more about KSystemLog [here](https://kde.org/applications/en/system/org.kde.ksystemlog).